# Braintree how to use stored credit card for payments

Tags: sdk, braintree, credit-card, pci-compliance, braintree-sandbox

I have the Nuxt (Vue2) application with Braintree DropIn implementation. Everything works except the stored cards. I would like to activate the card which was used as the last one on DropIn load. Actually the active card is the one which was stored as the first one. How can I achieve this. It should be simple but I don't see anything about it in [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/drop-in/overview).
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not fill out the annual Self-Assessment Questionnaire.

> You must fill out a Self-Assessment Questionnaire (SAQ) annually to help you determine if your payment processing setup is PCI compliant. The SAQ includes a series of yes-or-no questions for each applicable PCI DSS requirement.

for more about this check out the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/articles/risk-and-security/compliance/pci-compliance)

Comment: I dont understand. How is it related to the problem?

Comment: to store credit card you should be PCI compliant, if you did not fill out SAQ every year you will not be  PCI compliant and you cannot store and credit card data

Comment: Oh no. You changed the title of the question. It was Braintree how to activate last used credit card. I have not problem with store the card. But with the active one.

Comment: what do you mean by activate exactly?